# Can we use symmetry rules in improper integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

I wish to evaluate the integral $$I=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}xe^{-x^2}dx$$

Can I simply note that that $f(x)=xe^{-x^2}$ is an odd function and say $I=0$? The only reason I have doubts is because of assuming the two infinities have the same length. However, when I hear people say, "...the integral of an odd function vanishes on $\mathbb{R}$," it tempts me to accept the symmetry argument.

The actual answer via limits is $0$.

Comment: I think you can, if $\exists J=\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2}$ and $J < \infty$.

Comment: You should first separate the integral to 2 integrals with a single singularity/problematic point in each one (for example, separate to $[-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty]$).
If each one converges, than your claim that the integrand is odd is enough to say that the answer is 0

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, you can use that symmetry argument for improper integrals, but only after you proved that the integral exists (which is the case in your example). Otherwise, you might “deduce” that, say, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\,\mathrm dx=0$.

Comment: If a function is odd and vanishes in the limits, is there any case where you can not instantly jump to saying its -inf to inf integral is 0?

Comment: @iammax Sure, take any non-integrable function and mirror it. For example, $\frac{sgn(x)}{|x|+1}$

Comment: Hmm are we using Lebesgue or Riemann integration? Because with Riemann don't we have $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x \mathrm dx = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{-b}^{b} x \mathrm dx = 0$?

Comment: @Ovi No, we don't.

Comment: @iammax Another example is $\frac x{x^2+1}$. It's not enough to vanish; it has to vanish more quickly than $x^{-1}$; the integral of  $x^{-1}$ is $ln(x)$, which diverges.

Comment: This means that, if the integral exists, it is equal to its Cauchy principal value, right? If you could include a proof or proof sketch for this, instead of just implying it, I think your answer would be heavily improved (and I'd +1 in that case).

Comment: @Hamsterrific, it's already in my answer.

Answer (score 30):

One needs to be careful what $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \tag{1}$$ stands for. Most natural way to define it is as a double limit; let $F(a,b)\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be defined as $$F(a,b) = \int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm d x$$ and then define $(1)$ to be $$\lim_{(a,b)\to(-\infty,\infty)}F(a,b). \tag{2}$$

Existence of the double limit is pretty strong, it means that you can take any parametrized path $(a(t),b(t))$ in $\mathbb R^2$ such that $a(t)\to -\infty$ and $b(t)\to\infty$ when $t\to\infty$ and you will have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

In particular, take $a(t) = t$ and $b(t) = -t$ to get $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-t}^{t} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x. \tag{3}$$

You can use symmetry argument on $(3)$ to get what you want.

The RHS of $(3)$ is what is called the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). However, existence of Cauchy principal value does not imply the existence of the limit in $(2)$, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,\mathrm d x$ being the main such counterexample.

Comment: Will it be correct to state $a(t) = -t$ and $b(t) = t$ and let $t \rightarrow \infty$ or $a(t) = t$ and $b(t) = -t$ and let $t \rightarrow -\infty$ ?

Comment: @BAYMAX, well, $x\mapsto -x$ is a homeomorphism so it doesn't really matter, it's a very common substitution when dealing with limits. But as I've said, existence of double limit implies that limit is path independent, you might use $(a(t),b(t)) = (-t,t^2)$ or even $(-1/t,1/t)$ and let $t\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the primordial counterexample is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1x$ where the value of the integral depends on the *path* taken at 0.  Crossing infinitesimally "below" the pole yields a different sign from crossing infinitesimally "above".

Basically, analytic functions allow you to take any path through the complex plane with equal results as long as the different paths do not pass simple poles on different sides: any circular path integral for analytic functions is zero unless it encloses such points.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left|\,xe^{-x^2}\right|\,\mathrm{d}x=1
$$
we have that $xe^{-x^2}\in L^1$. Thus, it is valid to use symmetry.

If the function is not in $L^1$, such as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+1}$, one usually says that the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of the integral is $0$ by symmetry.

Comment: A function $f$ is in an [$L^p$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) on $E$ when $$\int_E|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\lt\infty$$